# Getting 404 error when adding Typekit fonts to Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1

I am attempting to add Typekit fonts to a Magento 2.1 install via Content > Design > Configuration > Default Store View > HTML Head. When I paste the Typekit provided embed code into the Scripts and Style Sheets and click Save Configuration I get a 404 Page not found error. If I edit any other field (for example I've updated the footer) there is no issue when I click Save Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

as per magento standard if you are tryinng to add new js,css or fonts to your magento website you need to add that in you theme folder.

here is the path
                          app/design/frontend/Vendor>/theme>/
Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

hope it will help you.